# Integration by Parts only of $\sqrt{1-u^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to integrate the function:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1-u^2}$$
I was using integration by parts to attack the problem, and it was:
$$\int\sqrt{1-u^2}du$$
I set $g=\sqrt{1-u^2}$ and $dv=du$

Thus leading me to get:
$$u\sqrt{1-u^2}+\int\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

from there I set $g=u$, and $dv=\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$

$$I=u\sqrt{1-u^2}-u\sqrt{1-u^2}-I$$

I somehow lose the inverse sine portion of the answer.

### Just using integration by parts is there a way I can get the right answer.

Comment: Hint: Let $u = sinx$ and $du = cosx dx$.

Comment: You forgot the sign in the integration by parts formula it should be a negative integral. I don't think you can solve this integral using integration by parts...

Comment: I believe one usually uses trig substitution for such things, try $u = \sin x$

Comment: Oh I misread, my hint is for substitution. I'm not sure about IbP.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks I did it the other way already thanks though, I looked up another similar question.

Comment: With that second substitution, you simply undo your first step... (And you have a sign error too; you should have gotten $I = (\cdots) + I$ instead of $I = (\cdots) - I$, leading to just $0=0$, which is useless.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $I = \int\sqrt{1-u^2}\, du$.

\begin{eqnarray*} I 
&=& u\sqrt{1-u^2} + \int \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du \\
&=& u\sqrt{1-u^2} - \int \frac{1-u^2 - 1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du \\
&=& u\sqrt{1-u^2} - I +\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du \\
&=& u\sqrt{1-u^2} - I + \arcsin(u)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

It follows:
$$2I = u\sqrt{1-u^2} + \arcsin(u) \leftrightarrow I = \frac{1}{2}\left( u\sqrt{1-u^2} + \arcsin(u)\right) (+ C)$$